# Can I branch from a water heater's supply and output lines for a utility sink?

Tags: plumbing

I'm adding a utility sink to our garage. The water heater is a few feet away, so the cold supply line comes out of the adjacent crawl space, heads up the wall to the heater, the hot water leaves and heads back to the crawl space.

Is there any reason I can't use these lines to supply the utility sink? SharkBite connectors to PEX, run along the wall to the sink?

In the attached picture, you can see the supply & output lines to the heater. I'd tee off of them, run PEX behind the HVAC unit to a sink in the corner.

[image]

Comment: Probably not, but a photo might reveal any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine. Take the cold water off of the line coming into your hot water heater, and the hot off of the line coming out.  Do this by placing T joints in the line.  I do suggest that you put turnoff valves in the lines from your heater.  This will let your house have water again while you're still connecting your utility sink.

Comment: Thanks for the second set of eyes. I attached a picture just for reference.

Comment: There's nothing I can see that would be too problematic.  I trust you already have a drain.  I would definitely continue the use of pipe insulation to the sink.

Comment: By the way, you may find the Plumber's Calc (https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/KurtHeckman/Plumbers+Calculator) useful in the project, especially if you have to calculate the rolling offset during the run to your sink.

Comment: Yes, there is a drain very close to the new sink location. Thanks.